# Show that $P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(E_k)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For an infinite sequence of events $E_1,E_2,E_3,\ldots$ show that $$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)\le  \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(E_k)$$

This is the question given to us. Now I know we can solve this by induction but is there any other method to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k   \right) \le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P\left( E_k   \right)$ ?

Comment: yes I meant that

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k   \right) \le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P\left( E_k   \right)$

This is true when the $E_k$ are mutually disjoint (countable addition of probability measure) and you get equality.

Define $F_k$ by $F_1=E_1$ and $F_k = E_k \backslash \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} E_j$ so the $F_k$ are mutually exclusive. Then

- $\mathbb P\left( F_k   \right)  \le \mathbb P\left( E_k   \right)$ since $F_k \subset E_k$
- $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} F_k = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k $ since any element of one is an element of the other
- so $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k   \right) =\mathbb P\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} F_k   \right) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P\left( F_k   \right) \le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P\left( E_k   \right)$

Which of these steps implicitly use induction, I leave to you

Comment: thank you so much